# How to copy Android files to Windows without ADB?

Tags: android, .net, file, copy, adb

I need to write an application in .Net 2010 to copy files from Android devices to the Windows computer.  I can use USB or other means, but not internet, which may not be available.  From what I understand, I would need to register each Android device on the Windows computer before I can copy using ADB over USB (is this correct?).

I need to be able to reliably copy files from many Android devices, one or two devices at a time, and I may not know which ones ahead of time.

Is there a way around the need to register the Androids?  Or is there an alternative to ADB?

Thanks,
Marty

Comment: I had used Regawmode AndroidLib for a similar case. It uses ADB. It enumerates connected devices so you can select them.

Comment: "I would need to register each Android device on the Windows computer before I can copy using ADB over USB (is this correct?)" -- correct. "Is there a way around the need to register the Androids?" -- write software for the Windows PC and Android that transfer files via Bluetooth or WiFiDirect.